# Pass in type Parameters<T> to a vararg function

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to call this function:

```
declare function foo(...args: any): Promise<string>;
```

`foo` is a declared function which represents a javascript 3rd party API call which can truly take a vast number of parameters.

The goal is to provide a list of possible function types to pass into a wrapper function which will help enforce the type of the parameters of this function. This wrapper function is generic and will take a type parameter of some other function type and use the parameters and return type of the other function to determine the parameters and return type of the actual function call.

```
async function fooWithType<T extends (...args: any) => string>(args: Parameters<T>): Promise<string> {
    return await foo(...args)
}
```

Here is an example of one possible function type that might be defined and how it would be used to aid in calling this 3rd party function via the wrapper function:

```
type funType = (a: string, b: boolean, c: number) => void;

fooWithType<funType>(["", true, 4])
```

However I'm getting an error seemingly telling me that I can't call the spread operator on `args?: Parameters<T>`.

```
Type 'Parameters<T>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Why isn't the spread operator doing what I expect here? I would expect to be able to spread this tuple argument into the vararg parameter of the `foo` function.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwAoA6M2AcwGcAueKVATwEo6AFGHAWyypAB4GjAHwBuAFDiMjAA4IUqACqyEAXnhEodKhhhZUFADTwARnROEIIBsbB1UyLiZAxm8VcPgA3HFmATxKCpGdCQ0TFx8REIAdSwMAAtlOX5FeBAADwwQVGAqDTISSlp6JjcPUpFNGGp2WCguEGyYKlThVngObl4BACUm5BglFTbPAG9xeCn4OAxB-CgAdyh4gmJC4uZxAF9JaJw4xOSBBWPhIgBtACIr411kEGMAFgBdZiA)

Comment: Why is `args` optional if you intend to use `args` as the parameters to `foo`? I think you should force the callee to pass an empty array if `foo` doesn't take any parameters instead of relying on the behavior of spreading undefined.

Comment: @kelsny I made it optional because I'd prefer to not have to pass in anything if the generic type doesn't have params. Just a shoddy workaround for passing in an empty array, though it's probably better to make it requried.

Comment: Well... it *is* the reason why you have this error. I think you *should* make it required...

Comment: Making the arg required yields more or less the same error
`Type 'Parameters<T> | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug in TypeScript that `Parameters<T>` for generic `T` constrained to `(...args: any) => any` isn't seen to be spreadable.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#36874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36874).

You can work around it by using the [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...Parameters<T>]` instead:

```
async function fooWithType<T extends (...args: any) => any>(
    args: [...Parameters<T>]
): Promise<string> {
    return await foo(...args);
}
```

or making the `T` constraint use `any[]` as the arg type instead of `any`:

```
async function fooWithType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
    args: Parameters<T>
): Promise<string> {
    return await foo(...args);
}
```

but given that `foo()` is so loosely typed, you might as well just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside the function to suppress the error:

```
async function fooWithType<T extends (...args: any) => any>(
    args: Parameters<T>
): Promise<string> {
    return await foo(...args as any);
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL3egFAOkOACcBzEALhmAjAEoqAFY9AW1RAFMAeEZY1BFIA+GAG8AsACgYsmMU7IExLACJknPqukBfadNCRYiFBixwcAdVTIAFgBUwABx72YnAB4aIAExAwCIjJKalo6GABeURowYVxpOWpgqgBtQnxGEmBWRU5iEG57YQBdaQYYZjYOHj4BIVFJGTkFJRVqAHdgG2w8dJJyOgBuXX0pQ2h4JCg0TB7rO0cXAEZC9y9OX39A-H6QmJTi8KjQ2Pim2V2mLJyNfMLhMqYWdi5efkERcQTmxWUsYE63QsvSCA2GUj0UlG42MUxm5isNgczk4ACZVp5vH4An1kicjtFaHFvhc8ZliNlcncio8Ks9qm86p9GokWn8Ol1kD1trtqP4YkNdEA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I'm confused about the syntax here, but if I end up calling `fooWithType<(a: string, b: boolean) => string>(["", true])`, will this still achieve the result of spreading the array and passing in `''` and `true` individually to `foo`?

Comment: Yes. I didn't change the runtime behavior; you're still spreading the passed-in array as individual parameters to `foo`.  You can check this [yourself](https://tsplay.dev/w8Vprm) if you want

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just miss brackets in your second function definition, as the `...args` is supposedly an array, then it's not simply `any` but `any[]`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwAoA6M2AcwGcAueKVATwEo6AFGHAWyypAB4GjAHwBuAFDioVRuiRpMufIkIB1LBgAWAFUYAHAdvggAHhhCpgVeKXIxqdIQG0Aus3gBeYfSbCilWng2WCguEHMYKn5tYVYgzh4+fgAlcOQYVF0DaOFvAG9xeCL4OAx0-CgAdygNAmIyEgDmcQBfSQx9BBRMzs8bKDoqDBgsVAoAGngAIzopwggQBkmwOlRkLimQGHcveAA3HCxgCXEVHHUtLIFuq78nACJ7yeHkEEmAFjdxAHpv+AA9AD8QA)

```ts
declare function foo(...args: any): Promise<any>;

// Here
async function fooWithType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(args: Parameters<T>): Promise<ReturnType<T>> {
    return await foo(...args)
}

type funType = (a: string, b: boolean, c: number) => void;

fooWithType<funType>(["", true, 4])
// ^? 
// function fooWithType<funType>(args: [a: string, b: boolean, c: number]): Promise<void>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to pass an array as a "single" (it's not exactly single) parameter, you'll need to either:

- Adjust your `funType` type in order to accept a tuple (= array of fixed size, here `3`) and not `3` separate arguments
- Spread your array while calling your function, see snippet below

```ts
declare function foo(...args: any): Promise<any>;

async function fooWithType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(...args: Parameters<T>): Promise<ReturnType<T>> {
    return await foo(...args)
}

type funType = (a: string, b: boolean, c: number) => void;

fooWithType<funType>(...["", true, 4]) // Spread tuple in order to pass each element as separate parameters
// ^?
// function fooWithType<funType>(a: string, b: boolean, c: number): Promise<void>
```

Comment: I did notice that this fixes the error, but won't this pass in the whole array as a single argument to `foo`?

Comment: I'll update my comment with another notation. The thing is, you are defining 3 separate parameters with your `funType` type, and you only pass one (the array). You might need to spread your arguments to do so

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think my comment might have been phrased in a confusing way.

The `foo` function shouldn't take an array of arguments. I want each argument in the tuple of the `args` parameter of `fooWithType` to be individually passed into `foo`.

Comment: Okay, then what I did in the second snippet is equivalent to `fooWithType<funType>("", true, 4)`. Is that ok for you ? I just kept the tuple notation as that's what was used in the post question